# count the filenames character and limit the file size to show Joptionpane

Tags: java, filenames, filesize

Im using Jfilechooser, if i select the file it will count the number of character of the file name however it will limit that if the file is more than 3kb, Joptionpane will show. my problem is even the file is 0kb, the Joptionpane will come out, i dont know if my code is right.

```
private int countWords(File f) {

    int filelength = 0;

    // Count of words.
    filelength = f.getName().length();

    double bytes = f.length();
    double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
    double limit = (1024 * 3);
    if (f.exists() && (kilobytes >= limit)) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "File Size:" + kilobytes + "KB", "Message Interrupted",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    return filelength;

}
```

Comment: Why not print out bytes or show it in the JOptionPane?

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
```

is taking the file bytes and converting it to kilo bytes (`1216 bytes` to `1.1875`)

This...

```
limit = (1024 * 3);
```

take 3 (kilobytes) and converting it to bytes (`3072.0`)

So, you end up comparing `1.875` to `3072` which isn't correct.  Instead drop one of the conversions, for example...

```
double bytes = f.length();
//double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
double limit = (1024 * 3);

if (f.exists() && (bytes >= limit)) { ... }
```

In my testing, I didn't have any issues with 0kb files

Comment: it work. Thank you.                                          double bytes = f.length(); 
    double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
    double limit = (1024 * 3);
    if (f.exists() && (bytes >= limit)) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "File Size:" + kilobytes + "KB", "Message Interrupted",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    return filelength;

}